# Better Practice: Less\greater than or equal to- OR less\greater than operator

Tags: java

Which would be considered the better practice(if any) between using the less/greater than or equal to- and using the less/greater than operator? For instance, if I want to test whether an integer is in a specific range, like between 5- and 10 inclusive,

```
if(integerNumber >= 5 && integerNumber <= 10){
\\do something
}
```

versus

```
if(integerNumber > 4 && integerNumber < 11){
\\do something
}
```

Is one considered to be the preferred practice?

---

EDIT: I am not asking for an alternative method for checking numbers in a range, my question concerns the practice of using `>= <=` VS `> <`.

Comment: i think both are same. lot of times i have seen >=

Comment: It depends on whether your range is conceptually open or closed at the specific end.  So if you had a range that was [0,10) (ie from zero up to, but not including 10), then `(range >= 0 && range < 10)` would be most appropriate IMO.  If on the other hand the range was [0,9] (ie from zero up to and including 9), then `(range >= 0 && range <= 9)` would be best.

Comment: @msandiford In this case I'm only considering closed intervals. Why would you say using    >=     <=     would be best?

Comment: Generally speaking, it would mean that you would have less constants in your code, and would be more conceptually easy for folks to understand when reading the code.  For example, if I prompted a user to "Enter a number between 1 and 100 inclusive", then (for me anyhow) it would create a bit of a logical disconnect if I then saw the range being checked as `(range > 0 && range < 101)`.

Comment: @msandiford That makes sense. I'll go with that. One last thing, how do you format your code like that in your comments?

Comment: Using the "Inline Code" backtick formatting mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: regardless of what your intent is, this is 100% opinion based ***and*** a duplicate because many have opinions that you shouldn't do what you are asking for **which is best** regardless. see the dupe for example -> *"Of course the above code is ugly and hard to read. So is there a better way?"*, personally I like the fluent style of [`Range.<Integer>open(5,10).contains(7);`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) - all about opinions!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I haven't been programming long enough to be able to discern whether this is opinion based or whether java code convention dictates one practice over the other. So that answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: First rule and only true answer of **what is best**, regardless of the question is, does it fulfill the following test; does this [Follow the Principal of Least Astonishment?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Put another way; *is this self explanatory enough and obvious what this does to someone that might not know what my intentions were at some time in the future? Could they interpret this correctly regardless of skill level using intuition alone?*

Comment: also, the deleted answer about 2 operations vs 1 is completely wrong, if you compile `boolean b = 1 < 2;` and `boolean b = 1 >= 2` you get the exact same byte code instructions for the comparison `LOCALVARIABLE b Z L1 L2 1`, the only instruction that changes is `ICONST_1` changes to `ICONST_0`. Just so you know don't trust anything about what a compiler does or does not do without examining the bytecode/asm yourself!

Comment: POLA seems like a safe rule to live by, I can see how that carries weight. Glad you mention the deleted answer, in my ignorance due to my limited exposure I would have considered it's validity.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding <= vs <, it doesn't really matter.

As a side note, it will make your code clearer if you emulate mathematical convention:

```
if(a <= x && x <= b){//Note how the x's are in middle.
    //Do ALL the things!
}
```

An example with real numbers:

```
if(5 <= x && x <= 10){ //This is much easier to read.
    //Do ALL the things!
}
```

Comment: That's a nice and clear touch, keeping lower bounds on the left and upper bounds on the right. Something to keep in mind.